# Call VBA Class Module in Excel formula

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I know that a function of a Module can be called in a formula like this:

```
=GetMyModuleFunction()
```

Now I would like to call a Class Module function. I don't know if a Class Module can be instantiated in a formula at all so I've created a function in a Module so I can call it just like `=GetMyModuleFunction()`:

```
' Class Module MyClassModule:
Public Property Get MyProperty() As String
    MyProperty = "Hello World!"
End Property

Public Function GetMyFunction() As String

    GetMyFunction = "Hello World!"

End Function
' End Class Module MyClassModule

' Module MyModule:
Public Function GetMyClassModule() As MyClassModule

   Set GetMyClassModule = New MyClassModule

End Function
' End Module MyModule
```

So after that I tried in the formula bar:

```
=GetMyClassModule().GetMyFunction()
=GetMyClassModule().MyProperty
```

Which shows an error dialog that the formula is invalid. Is it not possible what I'm trying to achieve here? Currently I use Modules instead but functions and subs  with duplicate names are confusing and error prone to use in Modules..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is similar to the question asked here: [Call VBA function that returns custom type from spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29904678/call-vba-function-that-returns-custom-type-from-spreadsheet)

> You can only return data types that Excel understands from a user-defined function. Excel does not understand custom data types.

But you can wrap your class properties or functions with a regular module function (UDF) like so:

```
Public Function GetMyClassModuleFunction() As String

    GetMyClassModuleFunction = GetMyClassModule.GetMyFunction()

End Function
```

Comment: So Excel only understands primitive types like String and Integer?

Comment: And arrays and a few more, but yes. Excel evaluates each part of a formula separately, so it needs to be something it knows how to handle. It can't guess what to do with custom types.