# Excel-VBA UDF: Keep 2 values but display only 1

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a user-defined function for fractions to be displayed with superscripted & subscripted digits (available in Unicode), with denominator no more than the user wants to. I could basically turn π into ²²/₇ with "=Fraction(PI(),30)", since no other fraction would be closer to π with a denominator smaller than or equal to 30.

Then I'm thinking of writing an InvFraction function as well, to get from a string generated by the Fraction function into an actual number. As you can imagine, though, the value is not π anymore, but 3.142857... (i.e. ²²/₇). So I'm postponing the writing until I remove that sense of chasing a ghost I'm feeling about it.

I saw that one could make the Fraction function generate a size-2 array of values, then through the index function, let the user decide which one to display, or enter the Fraction function as an array function covering 2 cells. Neither one is ideal from my perspective, the first option because the second value, which could be π, gets lost through the index choice and is no longer retrievable, the second option because it forces two cells to contain the data (though I guess I COULD end up living with it).

I also thought of using user-defined types containing the string value for the fraction and the double value for the original input, but I noticed they don't work in the actual sheet, then informally confirmed the info there: [Call VBA function that returns custom type from spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29904678/call-vba-function-that-returns-custom-type-from-spreadsheet)

Anyone would have any idea at how to tackle this? Thanks anyways for having taken the time to read.

*Edit:* To put it simply, if I were to program the *InvFraction* function as I conceived it with the tools and ideas I have, I could only manage to have “*=InvFraction(Fraction(PI(),30))*” to equal 3.142857... (22 divided by 7), but I would rather like it to generate 3.14159265... (π).

Comment: Look at [Craig Pearson's "Returning Arrays from VBA User Defined Functions"](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/returningarraysfromvba.aspx). But I'd recommend building two UDFs (probably with a common set of shared `Private` methods), one of which will return the first value and the other will return the second value. That requires less effort on the user's part to remember that they have to use `INDEX` to get the correct value.

Comment: If one and the other functions are used a few hundreds of times or possibly more in a single workbook, would there be a way to store both values for each occurrence through a _Private_ variable? Wouldn't that require a lot of _Redim Preserve_ over a dynamic array (I expect performance issues)? I half-suspect (or probably more than half-) that I misprocessed a tiny bit of info from your message, and that it could well unlock me straight if I was putting all the pieces in their right place.

Comment: You could use a module-global `Private` variable, yes. Look at `Dictionary` or `Collection` so that you wouldn't have to `ReDim`.

Comment: Nice! I'll definitely look into that. I'm not sure about the final result yet, but thanks anyway. It's very appreciated.